# how to set autosum property in x++ for a morphx report

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, morph-x

I have the following code in the init() of a report:

```
QueryBuildDataSource    qbdsTable;
QueryOrderByField       QueryOrderByFieldTransDate;
QueryOrderByField       QueryOrderByFieldDimZone
QueryOrderByField       QueryOrderByFieldDimCC;
;

super();

qbdsTable = query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(Table));
QueryOrderByFieldTransDate = qbdsTable.addOrderByField(fieldNum(Table, TransDate));
QueryOrderByFieldTransDate.autoSum(true);
QueryOrderByFieldDimZone = qbdsTable.addOrderByField(fieldNum(Table, DimZone),SortOrder::Descending);
QueryOrderByFieldDimZone.autoSum(true);
QueryOrderByFieldDimCC = qbdsTable.addOrderByField(fieldNum(Table, DimCostCenter));
QueryOrderByFieldDimCC.autoSum(true);
```

and the autosum property is functioning properly (I have set the SumAll property for the field I use to calculate these subtotals).

The problem is that, whenever I try to add an groupBy field or a selection field, the autosum property isn't honored anymore (the subtotals are not displayed anymore):

```
qbdsTable.addSelectionField(fieldNum(Table, AmountMST), selectionField::Sum);
```

or

```
qbdsTable.addGroupByField(fieldNum(Table, TransDate));
```

I have tried to use:

```
qbdsTable.addSortField(fieldNum(Table, TransDate));
qbdsTable.autoHeader(1, true);
```

but I have the same problem

Does anyone has an Idea how I can use both autosum and addGroupByField on the same datasorce of a report?

Answer (score 0):

For historical reasons old style AX reports behaves differently when called directly (run on the report node) or through on a report menu item.

The execution order of the first is:

1. init
2. fetch
3. dialog

The second runs via class `RunbaseReportStd` in the following order:

1. init
2. dialog
3. fetch

This matters because you have change the query *after* the user has made any changes.

So move your code changes from init to fetch, like this:

```
public boolean fetch()
{
    QueryBuildDataSource qbdsCustTrans = query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(CustTrans));
    ;
    qbdsCustTrans.addSelectionField(fieldNum(CustTrans, AmountMST), selectionField::Sum);
    qbdsCustTrans.addGroupByField(fieldNum(CustTrans, AccountNum));
    qbdsCustTrans.addGroupByField(fieldNum(CustTrans, TransDate));
    qbdsCustTrans.addGroupByField(fieldNum(CustTrans, CurrencyCode));
    //info(qbdsCustTrans.toString());
    return super();
}
```

This will only work, if called through the menu item.
Also, I could not get the auto-sum functionality to work, when added by code.

Instead you will have to add the order by and autosum using Sorting node of the report query.

I don't know why, but maybe this is because you use auto design, which is generated at run time.

Comment: I didn't post the whole code but I have qbdsTable.addGroupByField for every field displayed on the report;   I also have     qbdsTable.addSelectionField(fieldNum(Table, AmountMST), selectionField::Sum); and the query is generated like it supposed to 'SELECT SUM(AmountMST) FROM Table 
 GROUP BY Table.TransDate, Table.DimZone, Table.DimCostCenter
 ORDER BY Table.TransDate ASC, Table.DimZone DESC, Table.DimCostCenter ASC'

Comment: Consider reproducing the problem on standard tables then export to pastebin.com.

Comment: can you put it on pastebin.com, please? I have the demo VM  for AX2012 R3

Comment: the code written on the init method was just for testing; for the report I'm working on, I've written a class that extends RunBaseReport and calls the report from lastValueElementName(); either way, I had the same result. I'l try the fetch() aproach. Thank you for your support so far

Comment: the reason that I want to add autosum by code is to have multiple designs , each with different subtotals, for the same report. Maybe someone else have and ideea.